# How to run a single Cucumber feature file in different browsers/environments parallel in Browserstack?

Tags: java, cucumber, browser-automation, browserstack

I have created a simple Cucumber test in Java. Basically, when you run the feature file it goes to a website, selects a button and takes you to that page. What I would like to do is to run this test through BrowserStack. Not only that but to run this single feature file across a number of browsers/devices in Browserstack in parallel. e.g to run the same test across five different browsers/devices.

Comment: Which tool you are using? Is it Selenium? And which build tool? Maven?

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - Yes to both. Can I send you a link to my repo?

Comment: I have added the solution in the answer section, because it would be helpful to others as well. Try that and let me know, if you need any more help on this.

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - I think I am getting closer. However when I run the make browserstack_parallel command I receive the following message in the terminal: Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
I have definitely used tabs to indent as in your MakeFile code.

Comment: It is just the formatting issue, I would recommend to use the MakeFile plugin, if you are using IntelliJ, where you can easily format the lines and it will show the errors also.

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - Yes I am using Intellij and I have installed MakeFile plugin. I now receive the following error   ':','::' or <target expected, got '='  this appears for bs_windows_10_firefox_69: mvn test -Dbs_local_testing=false

Comment: can you share the Makefile you are using

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - Sure this is the link to the MakeFile https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgOm_ZWP6HuPaEzrujF-lX9l4X8?e=5f8BHR

Comment: I have updated the MakeFile, [Link to file](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ANAA4mzBiJrdDFw&cid=13D520F006E19CA9&id=13D520F006E19CA9%211404&parId=root&action=locate)

Comment: Thanks @SoorajSathianandan - I have replaced my MakeFile with yours. When I run 'make browserstack_parallel' now. although it seems to be building. The build fails and the simple test doesn't run. Link to project is https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgOm_ZWP6HuPafFkhw8MBSpsJq0?e=uGxENw

Comment: In your project you need to rename the package **feature** to **features** bcoz in the runner class you have mentioned **features**. And use command `make -j bs_windows_10_firefox_69 bs_windows_8.1_ie_11` to run the makefile from terminal.

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - Thanks for the information I have updated the project to suit. When I try to run the test in parallel using either the 'make browserstack_parallel' or the one above in your comments the tests still fail. Link to the update project is as follows https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgOm_ZWP6HuPag16jYnyCuyboqM?e=QMQdaL

Comment: add the dependency for **cucumber-junit** in the POM

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - I'm using cucumber-testng to run it as shown in the POM. When I do add the dependency as you suggesting above I receive a lot of errors in the terminal on Intellij.

Comment: please share the github repository

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - github repo as follows https://github.com/FazEngineer/testautomationbrowserstack

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - I believe it is macOS Mojave

Comment: Your browserstack doesn't have enough minutes to try your code

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - I have obtained an additional 100 minutes please pull the latest changes from my repo.

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - Can you please also send me your Github username so I can add you to my repo so you can make amendments to it also.

Comment: Add the `cucumber-junit` dependency to pom.xml, I tried and it works, I don't have permission to push the code to your repository

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - Updated the pom.xml to include the cucumber-junit.  Ran the following command `make -j bs_windows_10_firefox_69 bs_windows_8.1_ie_11` from terminal I still receive an error.  Part of it is shown below  `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project test-automation-browserstack: http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]   TestRunner>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature:21 » 0
[INFO] 
make: *** [bs_windows_8.1_ie_11] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.`

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan - Do you have a github username so I can provide you with permissions?

Comment: My github username is _soorajs95_

Comment: Thanks @SoorajSathianandan I have made you a collaborator now so you should be able to push your changes.

Comment: Still I'm not able to push....
**Push failed Remote: Permission to FazEngineer/testautomationbrowserstack.git denied to soorajs95**

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan try the following link https://github.com/FazEngineer/testautomationbrowserstack/invitations

Comment: The push is successful now

Comment: @sooraj - I have pulled your changes ran both the `make -j bs_windows_10_firefox_69 bs_windows_8.1_ie_11` and `make browserstack_parallel` command through intellij terminal and I still receive failed messages `[INFO] Fmake[1]: *** [bs_windows_10_firefox_69] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
inished at: 2019-12-21T21:37:13Z
[INFO] ----
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project test-automation-browserstack: There are test failures.` Not sure how to proceed with this further.

Comment: For me it is working perfectly fine with the same code that I pushed to your repo.
I don't know what is wrong on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites:

You should have:

1. ***maven-surefire-plugin*** and ***cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin***
2. ***BrowserStack*** account(*username* and *accesskey*)

Then use the below code to connect and run the tests in BrowserStack

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", System.getProperty("bs_local_testing"));
caps.setCapability("browser", System.getProperty("bs_browser"));
caps.setCapability("browser_version", System.getProperty("bs_browser_version"));
caps.setCapability("os", System.getProperty("bs_os"));
caps.setCapability("os_version", System.getProperty("bs_os_version"));
caps.setCapability("browserstack.selenium_version", System.getProperty("bs_selenium_version"));
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://username:accesskey@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Then you need to create a ***Makefile*** in your project with the below lines of code

```
browserstack_parallel:
    make -j bs_windows_10_firefox_69 bs_windows_8.1_ie_11

bs_windows_10_firefox_69:
    mvn test -Dbs_local_testing=false -Dbs_browser=Firefox -Dbs_browser_version=69.0 -Dbs_os=Windows -Dbs_os_version=10 -Dbs_selenium_version=3.141.59

bs_windows_8.1_ie_11:
    mvn test -Dbs_local_testing=false -Dbs_browser=IE -Dbs_browser_version=11.0 -Dbs_os=Windows -Dbs_os_version=8.1 -Dbs_selenium_version=3.141.59
```

After that you can run the Makefile from the terminal using the command

`make browserstack_parallel`